# How to convert a number into two numbers in the scientific notation?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have integer number in input, for example

```
6456
```

I would like to find the quickest way to transform it into two numbers

```
6.456 and 1000
```

Comment: That would be [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), not decimal notation.

Comment: Have you tried simply formatting using `"E"` as the format? It doesn't match your required output but it is closer.

Comment: What do you expect to get for -1234? -12.34?

Comment: Anatoly, your edit has completely changed your question . What have you tried/researched? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this Method to determine your string

```
public static string ConvertExp(int Value)
{
    int exp = Math.Abs(Value).ToString().Length -1;
    return string.Format("{0} * 10^{1}",( Value / Math.Pow(10 , exp)), exp);
}
```

and to get 2 values

```
public static double[] ConvertExp(int Value)
{
    int exp = Math.Abs(Value).ToString().Length -1;
    return new double[] { Value / Math.Pow(10, exp), Math.Pow(10, exp) };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an algorithm, just use [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Integer does not hold format information, but they can be displayed as formatted strings. in your case, you need to call `ToString()` and specify the format to display: `6456.ToString("e3")`

Comment: You might want to specify the proper format string to accomplish that :)

Comment: @Luaan: Just did. (I wanted to make sure first that I've got the correct format)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I need two numbers, so I need algorithm, not Format

Comment: Neat, Format is really full of gems. Doesn't solve the OP's homework, but usefull!

Comment: @Anatoly: shifting the goal post is something you should avoid. I wrote my answer based on what you asked in your original question. Getting 2 different numbers out of a single one is not the same as representing a number in a different notation. Seems like fubo has an answer to your question as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you want to diplay your number in scientific notation. For that you can use String.Format function like this:

```
label1.Text = string.Format("{0:E2}", MyNumber.ToString());
```

if you want to do the reverse :

```
decimal x = decimal.Parse("1.2345E-02", NumberStyles.Float);
```